# How to insert mutiple rows at one submit in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have an exchange rate table that I want to insert for more than one country.

This is my form

```
<? form_open_multipart('exchange/create')
?>
<input  type="text" name="user[0][ExchangeRateDate]"/>
<input  type="text" name="user[0][CountryId]"/>
<input  type="text" name="user[0][CashSelling]"/>
<input  type="text" name="user[0][CashBuying]"/>
<input  type="text" name="user[0][TransferSelling]"/>
<input  type="text" name="user[0][TransferBuying]"/>
<input  type="text" name="user[0][InsertDate]"/>
<input  type="text" name="user[0][Status]"/>

<input  type="text" name="user[1][ExchangeRateDate]"/>
<input  type="text" name="user[1][CountryId]"/>
<input  type="text" name="user[1][CashSelling]"/>
<input  type="text" name="user[1][CashBuying]"/>
<input  type="text" name="user[1][TransferSelling]"/>
<input  type="text" name="user[1][TransferBuying]"/>
<input  type="text" name="user[1][InsertDate]"/>
<input  type="text" name="user[1][Status]"/>
<input type="submit" value="insert exchange" class="btn"/>
</form>
```

Here is the model code for the current form

```
public function set_exchange() {
    $data = array('ExchangeRateDate' => $this -> input -> post('ExchangeRateDate'),
   'CountryId' => $this -> input -> post('CountryId'),
   'CashSelling' => $this -> input -> post('CashSelling'),
   'CashBuying' => $this -> input -> post('CashBuying'),
   'TransferSelling' => $this -> input -> post('TransferSelling'),
   'TransferBuying' => $this -> input -> post('TransferBuying'),
   'InsertDate' => $this -> input -> post('InsertDate'),
 'Status' => $this -> input -> post('Status'));
   return $this -> db -> insert('exchange_rate', $data);    
    }
```

And at end this is the controller code

```
public function create() {
        
        $this -> load -> helper('form');
        $this -> load -> library('form_validation');
        $data['title'] = 'Create a news exchange rate';
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('ExchangeRateDate', 'ExchangeRateDate', 'required');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('CountryId', 'CountryId', 'required');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('CashSelling', 'CashSelling', 'required');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('CashBuying', 'CashBuying', 'required');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('TransferSelling', 'TransferSelling', 'required');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('TransferBuying', 'TransferBuying', 'required');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('InsertDate', 'InsertDate', 'required');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('Status', 'Status', 'required');
        $this -> all -> set_exchange();
        $this -> load -> view('admin/exchange/create');

    }
```

Table structure

```
ExchangeRateId
ExchangeRateDate
CountryId
CashSelling
CashBuying
TransferSelling
TransferBuying
InsertDate
Status
```

The idea is everything works fine I insert a new row the data goes to my database but
here I want to insert more than one rows at the time only the **ID** is not duplicate but other are, so as my form I use from other stuck overflow but it's not working

Comment: Can you share what selects/inserts your model produces? I mean turn on profiler (in constructor `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);`) thanks. Take a look at batch insert in this help guide http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert And after all I don't see any question mark in your question :)

Comment: @Kyslik, yes your right the mvc works fine, but the question is, i wanto insert more then one row, same comlumn names, wish i could clear my question.

Comment: Please do a little example with (2 columns) in comments what you are trying to achieve. lets say we have table structure as follows `id` | `name` after submiting the form there are two sets of data (for `user[0]` and for `user[1]` right?

Comment: yes, here i want to add
(row first is like((id=1, name=ab)) 
and on the second row((id=2, name=ahmad)) 
so here i will make an input for (4) in once submite i wanto insert both rows at one time

Comment: Now I understand, will think about it. Do you require batch insert ? (one insert with 2+ sets of data) or two+ separate inserts but still in one submission?

Comment: seperate insert 
i will make form ---> for example if i want to insert to **row** so i will make four input---i mean tow for each and i will insert my data on to the form. first tow input as i will mention their name will go to the first row and the second to input will insert data to secound row... this the concept.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your **model** should look something like this

```
public function set_exchange($data) {
    $this->db->insert('exchange_rate', $data);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() == '1') return TRUE;
    return FALSE;    //error ocures
}
```

your **controller** should look like this

```
if(isset($_POST['insert_exchange'])) {
    //triggers only if form is sent
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    //$forms_sent = count($user); //this line is useless
    foreach ($user as $id => $index) {
        //$data['id'] = $id; //note 1 depends on your table structure
        foreach ($index as $key => $value) {
            $data[$key] = $value;
        }
        $this -> all -> set_exchange($data);
        var_dump($data); //for debug only
        unset($data);
    }
}
```

**output**

```
Array ( [id] => 0 [ExchangeRateDate] => TestingValue1.1 
                  [CountryId] => TestingValue1.2 
                  [CashSelling] => TestingValue1.3 
                  [CashBuying] => TestingValue1.4 
                  [TransferSelling] => TestingValue1.5 
                  [TransferBuying] => TestingValue1.6 
                  [InsertDate] => TestingValue1.7 
                  [Status] => TestingValue1.8 ) 

Array ( [id] => 1 [ExchangeRateDate] => TestingValue2.1 
                  [CountryId] => TestingValue2.2 
                  [CashSelling] => TestingValue2.3 
                  [CashBuying] => TestingValue2.4 
                  [TransferSelling] => TestingValue2.5 
                  [TransferBuying] => TestingValue2.6 
                  [InsertDate] => TestingValue2.7 
                  [Status] => TestingValue2.8 )
```

as for `HTML`
`<?= form_open_multipart('exchange/create')?>` **EDIT** - the *equals sign*
or 
`<?php echo form_open_multipart('exchange/create');?>`
`<input type="submit" name="insert_exchange" value="insert exchange" class="btn"/>`

*note1:*
depends on structure of your table I assume it looks similar to this
`id | ExchangeRateDate | CountryId | CashSelling ...` etc. so ID is a must have in insert :)

*sidenote:*
For future I recommend naming all models as follows `customer_model.php`, views as follows `customer_view`.

Comment: sorry it's not working here, on my own MVC only one row inserts not other, if u just edit my MVC so will great, thanks

Comment: can you [edit] your question and add table structure? Also I need to see output of profiler, put this line `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` anywhere in your controller, run the script like usualy and scroll down and see "DATABASE QUERIES" copy it in here somewhere (preferably in your question)

Comment: I hope you understand what _my_ controller does, it grabs all `$_POST` variables into one array called `$user` (as you can see its x*x size), for each `user[id]` it is creating `$data` variable that is sent to model. There is no way to edit your controller to fit your needs (only hardcoded), please try understand my code try echoing & debugging so you understand it well.